# Saving descriptions for different StoreViews does not work

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to update the descriptions of existing products. But I only want to update the description for specific StoreViews without altering the default values.

My code so far:

```
<?php    
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(42);
$product
    ->setStore(3)        //StoreView #3 is specific for english language
    ->setData(array(
        'name' => 'English name',
        'short_description' => 'English short desc',
        'description' => 'English desc'
    ))
    ->save();
?>
```

After running, the descriptions and name of the product's default values have changed. When I open the product in backend and select my english StoreView, the description fields have the "Use Default" checkbox checked.

What am I missing here?

Comment: In this case you should use addData(...) instead of setData(...) - the latter will replace all the product object's properties with your array, which will result in Magento trying to create a new product and throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the store id before loading the product. In your case you have set the attribute "store" on the product to the value 3. Try:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(3)->load(42);
$product->setData(
    ...
```

Comment: You're right, but take heed of Oleg Ishenko's comment: passing an array to setData() will overwrite everything. That means no Product ID (among others). That means a new product on save, not an update, as OP would want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As Oleg and nevvermind state, it now sets the correct description for the given store, but all other attributes "Use Default" checkbox is now unchecked. Even when I use addData()  I'll try to find a way :)